# www to http resolve for Rails app on passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, redirect, passenger

I am running a rails app on phusion passenger. I want to resolve all `www` addresses to http for SEO benefits.

I am using phusion along with the apache server and for performance benefits would like the redirect to be in the `httpd.conf` file instead of the .htaccess file. I added the redirect in the `httpd.conf` file but it redirects to the public folder of the application on every url request. I wrote to my hosting provider and got the following response:

Since passenger is configured for your rails application via .htaccess, the direct rules through htaccess will not work. But, htaccess directs will work fine with non rails applications.

```
If you really wish to redirect www.xyz.com to xyz.com, you have to add a code similar to the following in your application.

-------
before_filter :check_uri

def check_uri
  if /^www/.match(request.host)
    redirect_to request.protocol + request.host_with_port[4..-1] + request.request_uri
  end
end
```

I think this is not good for performance of the application. Is there any way I can redirect from the httpd.conf file itself?

Here is the httpd.conf file:

## This redirects www to the public folder instead of http

```
<Directory "/home/xyz">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</Directory>


    <VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    SuexecUserGroup "#500" "#501"
    ServerName xyz.com
    ServerAlias www.xyz.com
    ServerAlias webmail.xyz.com
    ServerAlias admin.xyz.com
    #DocumentRoot /home/xyz/public_html
    DocumentRoot /home/xyz/public
    
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
    
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.xyz.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://xyz.com:20000/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.xyz.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://xyz.com:10000/ [R]
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php5
    IPCCommTimeout 31
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
    <Files awstats.pl>
    AuthName "xyz.com statistics"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/xyz/.awstats-htpasswd
    require valid-user
    </Files>
    Alias /dav /home/xyz/public_html
    <Location /dav>
    DAV on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "xyz.com"
    AuthUserFile /home/xyz/etc/dav.digest.passwd
    Require valid-user
    ForceType text/plain
    Satisfy All
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php5
    RewriteEngine off
    </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What happens if you move the rewrite rule you added to the virtual host rather than the directory context?

Comment: Haven't tried that. I have limited understanding of the httpd.conf